# What does "loss of regularity" mean?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, soft-question

I have seen a lot the phrase "loss of regularity" in references regarding PDE. (For instance, there are questions like "do solutions of 3D Navier-Stokes equations lose regularity or not?")

Could anybody explain what "loss of regularity" means in research regarding PDE?

Comment: This usually means that the solutions are less regular than the functions in the equations or the initial data.

Comment: Say you have a solution $u(t,x)$, you've lost regularity if at some time $u(t,x)$ has fewer derivatives than $u(0,x)$ did. A classic way for this to happen is with a nonlinear transport equation like $u_t + (1-u)u_x=0$: here certain continuous initial conditions will lead to shocks (solutions with jump discontinuities in space).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of an answer:

> This usually means that the solutions are less regular than the functions in the equations or the *initial data*.